# Timestamp off by 1 hour

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am using Laravel 9 app. In my config/app.php I am using

```
  'timezone' => 'America/Toronto'
```

However, the timestamp I am getting in the SQL table is off by 1 hour, that is instead of 2022-04-15 19:06:53, my table contains 2022-04-15 20:06:53. Not sure, if this issue is linked to daylight saving that is applicable in Toronto these days (April). Also want to add that my shared hosting server is with Dreamhost, which is in LA, USA.

So, in addition to timezone setting in config/app.php, is there anything else I need to do to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you see the php.ini file? If you can change the php.ini file the problem will be solved.

It will be enough to update the **date.timezone** value in the php.ini file.

You need to restart the server after this change.

Comment: It is a shared server, do I can't restart the server. I was hoping that somehow, I should be able to do it using some configuration setting in Laravel.

Comment: As a solution, I think of the feature that we will manipulate the data during registration to the database. This feature is called mutators. I hope it works for you. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator

Comment: Koray, as advised by Laravel documentation, I plan to keep timestamp in UTC format and convert it to required timezone using MySQL convert_tz(). At present, I don't plan to use mutators.